# Detecting all cycles in a directed graph with millions of nodes in Ocaml

Tags: graph, ocaml, graph-algorithm

I have graphs with thousands of nodes to millions of nodes. I want to detect all possible cycles in such graphs.

I use hash table to store the edges. ( (source node,edge weight) -> (target node) ).

What can be the efficient way of implementing it in OCaml?

Its looks like Tarjan's algorithm is the best one.

What can be the most implementation for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tarjan's algorithm for strongly connected components is a good solution. You may also use so-called [path-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm) strong component algorithms which have (when done carefully) comparable linear complexity.

If you pick reasonable data structures, they should work. It's hard to say much more before you implemented and profiled a prototype implementation.

I don't understand what your graph representation is: are you hashed keys really a `(node,weight)` couple? Then how do you find all neighbors of a given node? For a large graph structure you should optimize access time, of course, but also memory efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find all possible cycles, the problem seems at least exponential in the worst case.  For a complete graph, every nonempty subset of nodes gives you a different cycle (including a link from the last back to the first).  Forthermore every cyclic permutation of every subset gives you a different cycle.  Depending on the sparsity of your graphs, the problem could be tractable in practice.

Comment: It looks like each node has,on an average, 2 edges which makes it sparse.

Comment: Sounds good.  Estimating the number of cycles as a function of sparseness is out of my league, but an interesting question.  I found a paper on this topic by googling, so it appears to have been studied.  At a very quick glance, the limit doesn't look too bad.